tbl_regression and tbl_uvregression for survey-weighted negative binomial regression
I am using the gtsummary package to build various tables. However, I am encountering problems when creating tables with tbl_regression and tbl_uvregression when the results come from a survey-weighted binomial regression fitted with the svyVGAM package.
To illustrate the issue more clearly, I created the example below to highlight the error that R points out.
library(survey)
library(svyVGAM)
library(gtsummary)

# Example dataset
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000

# Example data
example_data <- data.frame(
  n_events = rpois(n, lambda = 2),  # Count outcome variable
  age = rnorm(n, mean = 45, sd = 15),
  income = rnorm(n, mean = 3000, sd = 1000),
  education = rnorm(n, mean = 8, sd = 2),
  sex = factor(rbinom(n, 1, 0.5), labels = c("Male", "Female")),  # Changed to sex as factor
  survey_weight = runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)  # Survey weights
  )

# Create survey design
svy_design <- svydesign(
  ids = ~1,  # No clustering
  weights = ~survey_weight,
  data = example_data
  )

# Fit negative binomial model
nb_model <- svy_vglm(
  n_events ~ age + income + education + sex,
  family = negbinomial(),
  design = svy_design
  )

# View summary
summary(nb_model)

When I run the scripts, the following errors appear:
> tbl_mutually_adjusted <- tbl_regression(
+   nb_model,
+   exponentiate = TRUE,
+   tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters
+   )
✖ Unable to identify the list of variables.

This is usually due to an error calling `stats::model.frame(x)`or `stats::model.matrix(x)`.
It could be the case if that type of model does not implement these methods.
Rarely, this error may occur if the model object was created within
a functional programming framework (e.g. using `lappy()`, `purrr::map()`, etc.).
> tbl_unadjusted <- tbl_uvregression(
+   nb_model,
+   exponentiate = TRUE,
+   tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters
+   )
Error in UseMethod("tbl_uvregression") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_uvregression' applied to an object of class "svy_vglm"
> 


Could be related to this open issue on GH? https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1684

Yes. Thanks Daniel!
